# Highcharts column stacking within a series only

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnd62ocb/

I am trying to achieve the result in the picture below.  I would like each series independent of each other series, but the points stacked intra-series.

[image]

Putting `stacking: true` in a single series made sense at first, but as this is added to other series, the series themselves start stacking.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the stack property on each series to define on which "stack" each datapoint accumulates

http://jsfiddle.net/mnd62ocb/1/

`series: [{
        data: [[0,10],[1,20],{x:1,y:30,color:'magenta'}],
        stacking: true,
        stack: 0,
    }, {
        data: [[0,10],[1,7],{x:1,y:3,color:'cyan'}],
        stacking: true,
        stack: 1
    }`